# How do I found exact matches in python in a `for` clause with many conditions?

Tags: python

For example, I have this list:

```
full_text = ["This is Archie. He is a rare Norwegian Pouncing Corgo.", 
"This is Darla. She commenced a snooze mid meal.", 
"Here we have a majestic great"]
```

I want to identify the first clause as containing a "He" and the third clause as *not* containing a "He".

But I don't know how to use a regular expression in this code:

```
gender = []

for f in full_text:
    words = f.split(" ")
    if any (["He" in f, "boy" in f, "him" in f, "his" in words]):
        gender.append(0)
    elif any (["She" in f, "girl" in f, "her" in f, "hers" in words]):
        gender.append(1)
    else:
        gender.append(-1)
```

The result I get is [0, 1, 1]. The result I want is [0, 1, -1].

Comment: What does this have to do with `pandas`?

Comment: @rachelvsamuel: Why do you use `in f` instead of `in words`? The result that i get is: `[0, 1, 0]`

Comment: @stovfl When I put `in words` in instead of `in f` I get weird results. Can you show where you put `in words`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: .. due to case sensitivity to be more precise

I agree, to be more *general* your const, e.g. `["he", "boy", "him", "his"]` and `words`, `["here", "we", "have"]`, should be all *lowercase*.

---

> **Question**:  Can you show where you put in words?

```
gender = []

for f in full_text:
    words = f.split(" ")
    if any ([term in words for term in ["He", "boy", "him", "his"]]):
        gender.append(0)
    elif any ([term in words for term in ["She", "girl", "her", "hers"]]):
        gender.append(1)
    else:
        gender.append(-1)

print(gender)  
>>> [0, 1, -1]
```

---

> `OOP` solution: Using **early break**.

```
class Gender:
    male = ["He", "boy", "him", "his"]
    female = ["She", "girl", "her", "hers"]

    def __init__(self, words):
        self.value = -1
        for value, terms in enumerate([Gender.male, Gender.female]):
            if self.match(words, terms):
                self.value = value
                break

    def match(self, words, terms):
        for term in terms:
            if term in words:
                return True
        return False      

gender = []

for f in full_text:
    words = f.split(" ")
    gender.append(Gender(words).value)

print(gender)  
>>> [0, 1, -1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `==` instead of `in`? E.g. `'Her' in 'Here'` would evaluate to True but is not what you want I guess.

Comment: @MrFuppes: Where do i use `'Her' in 'Here'`?

Comment: That's just an example. Your code actually compares 'Here' to 'her' which is why I'd say this just works by coincidence, or due to case sensitivity to be more precise.

Comment: @MrFuppes: Got your point. This `term in words`, and `term == 'He'`, `words == ["Here", "we", "have"]`. This is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`. Read [operator in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)

Comment: You're right, words is a `list`! I overlooked that.